# What is the best way to bind dynamically created control to a property in reactiveui?

Tags: reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI for Winforms 6.5. I'm trying to bind dynamically created textbox to a ViewModel property. Bind method doesnt allow to create such a binding.Is there any way to create binding in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need one-way binding (view model to view) only, you can use ***BindTo*** method:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(model => model.PropertyToBind)
         .BindTo(textBox, t => t.Text);
```